# What is this error ? ValueError invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python

I have an error with my code. When I run this code and I define `"email"`, Pycharm indicates an error.

```py
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'mymail'
```

```py
email = str(input("Define your email adress. "))
key_password = int(input("Define your password. "))

login = int(input("Input your email adress. "))
enter_password = int(input("Input your password. "))

if email == login and  key_password == enter_password:
    print("Welcome to your member space.")
elif email == login and  key_password != enter_password:
    print("Wrong password.")
elif email != login and  key_password == enter_password:
    print("Wrong email adress.")
else:
    print("Wrong email adress and password.")
```

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: It's Python 3.8

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your error comes from here:

```
login = int(input("Input your email adress. "))
```

You're trying to interpret your input as an `int` when it will probably be an email address. Maybe you meant to do the following?

```
login = str(input("Input your email adress. "))
```

As the comments indicated the `str()` here is redundant since `input()` returns a string. So you could just do:

```
login = input("Input your email adress. ")
```

Comment: [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) already returns a string

Comment: One caveat: `input()` does not need to be cast to `str()`, it already takes the input as a string

Comment: You're welcome @LuciferFr, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider upvoting it and accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Cheers!